# how to ask google to repair nexus 4?

Tags: google-play-store, nexus-4

Glass on my Nexus 4 is broken (touch doesn't work) after it falled from relatively small bed (just about 50 centimeters from the floor).

I purshased Nexus 4 on google play, can they fix this by warranty or for pay (how much?)

I've tried to call US support team from [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3053039) but it is not possible. When I press '3' in Skype they do not recognize that and keep asking me to make a decision.

[image: broken nexus 4 photo]

Answer (score 0):

Cracking your screen most likely isn't covered through a warranty. This is a good reason why you should purchase a screen protector. Mime Ghost Glass would be my recommendation as far as screen protectors go...

You can try to email Google's support: googleplay-support@google.com, explain what happened and you can probably pay to get it repaired, however the Nexus 5 should be coming out in the very near future for $350 so it may be better to just purchase a new device for a little more as screen repairs are usually $100+